USB disk on a VBox on RAID was repartitioned
I have an Ubuntu on a VBox on Windows 10 Pro. The Ubuntu had a Raid 1+0 with 2 external USB disks. Suddenly, when I restarted the server, both disks got repartitioned with these: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition"
Both disks are USB, and they were presented directly to the VM.
Now, I cannot access my Raid, Linux does not recognize the disk, and I don't have access at all.
Is there a way to remove that Microsoft partition and put back the raid?
